# When I try to use vim character command f with a python file, it says no fold found

Tags: vim

I want to use the `f` command (to go to next occurence of a character) in a python file but somehow this is masked by code folding function.

`:set nofoldenable` doesn't work.

These options are in my `.vimrc`:

```
filetype off
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

Does someone know which plug-in causes this behavior and how I can toggle between the two functionalities?

Here is the output of `:scriptnames`

```
 1: ~/.vimrc
  2: /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/ftoff.vim
  3: /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
  4: /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin.vim
  5: /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/indent.vim
  6: /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
  7: /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim
  8: /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
  9: ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim
 10: ~/.vim/bundle/SWTC.vim/plugin/SWTC.vim
 11: ~/.vim/bundle/SWTC.vim/plugin/rng.vim
 12: ~/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim/plugin/jedi.vim
 13: ~/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim/autoload/jedi.vim
 14: ~/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/autoloclist.vim
 15: ~/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/balloons.vim
 16: ~/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/checker.vim
 17: ~/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/cursor.vim
 18: ~/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/highlighting.vim
 19: ~/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/loclist.vim
 20: ~/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/modemap.vim
 21: ~/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/notifiers.vim
 22: ~/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/registry.vim
 23: ~/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/signs.vim
 24: ~/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic.vim
 25: ~/.vim/bundle/syntastic/autoload/syntastic/util.vim
 26: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-show-whitespace/plugin/showwhite.vim
 27: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-surround/plugin/surround.vim
 28: /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 29: /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/plugin/gzip.vim
 30: /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/plugin/matchparen.vim
 31: /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the `map f` command to see if there's a mapping for the <kbd>f</kbd> key.

If there is such a mapping, you can see which configuration file mapped the key by running `verbose map f`. It should report something like:

```
Last set from ~/.vim/some-plugin.vim
```